# form POST event not handled

Tags: php, html, forms

this is my form code :

```
 <form name="input" action="index.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Subscribe to Our News" onclick="value=''"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Sign up" id="submit"/>
 </form>
```

This is my post event code in the same page index.php

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo $email;
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO subscribe (email) VALUES ('$email')");

    if($sql){
        echo 'True';
    }else{
        echo 'false';
    }
}
```

I don't get the reply back from the click event! pls help me!

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give your submit button a name, in order to check if it was pressed:

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign up" id="submit" name="submit"/>
```

Comment: Thanks mate! :) I will Accept Your answer after 11 mins! :) since the rule on StackOverflow!